# How to map an XML tag by using another tag attribute?

Tags: python, xml, attributes, mapping, elementtree

I want to mapping a tag of XML. I want to use a string to mapping that tag. I tried this, it only able to mapping if the filter writes it directly, I can't use a variable as a string to mapping it.

If I used this way, it will return empty:

```
variablecode = "10.010"
ReadXML = ET.parse(XMLFile)
for drv in ReadXML.findall('.//desc[@code="variablecode"]/'):
   descname = drv.get('name')
   print(descname)
```

But if I use this way it return the name:

```
variablecode = "10.010"
ReadXML = ET.parse(XMLFile)
for drv in ReadXML.findall('.//desc[@code="10.010"]/'):
   descname = drv.get('name')
   print(descname)
```

Here is my XML file:

```xml
<Data>
     <family no="1309" description="date">
          <desc name="rt1" code="10.010" />
               <disk name="xsfdf" ver="9.11" />
               <disk name="jhgjt" ver="sryj" />
          </desc>
          <desc name="rt2" code="10.9" />
               <disk name="kury" ver="45.11" />
               <disk name="jyd" ver="liud" />
          </desc>
     </family>
     <family no="2006" description="date">
          <desc name="rt3" code="16450.010" />
               <disk name="ytdts" ver="9.11" />
               <disk name="sj" ver="8346" />
          </desc>
          <desc name="rt5" code="165460.9" />
               <disk name="kgd" ver="65.11" />
               <disk name="asdr" ver="97.986" />
          </desc>
     </family>
</Data>
```

But my expectation I don't want to write the code directly, I need to use variable, because the value of the code is defined by another process, that's why I need to use it in variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that when you pass it like this

```
for drv in ReadXML.findall('.//desc[@code="variablecode"]/'):
```

It's probably not referring to the value of the variable but referring solely to the string `variablecode`, which of-course does not exist in your `.xml` file and hence returns empty.
Can you try something like this?

```
for drv in ReadXML.findall('.//desc[@code="{}"]/'.format(variablecode)):
```

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly. Thanks Buddy! @AzyCrw4282